# json jquery .. get value number of duplicate

Tags: jquery, json

```
// for example
var arrayName = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2];
alert ( arrayName[2].length ); // undefined
```

What I want is

```
alert ( arrayName[2].length ); // 3
```

Or any other way .. thank you

Comment: `arrayName[2]` (which means "3rd element of `arrayName` array") is a number `2`. A number doesn't have `length` property

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: it's more likely "not clear what you're asking". According to the "expected result" OP doesn't want just a number of unique elements, since it would be 4, not 3

Comment: It's both, really.  Both on hold conditions apply here

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of `2`'s in the array you can do

```
var instances = arrayName.filter(function(e) {
    return e===2;
}).length;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NU2L9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lenght. Just reference the value at that index:

```
alert(arrayName[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your array prototype and you can return a unique subset from the array:

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}
```

This is a duplicate of [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array/1961068#1961068)

Comment: -1 for plagiarism http://stackoverflow.com/a/1961068/251311 If you "borrow" a solution - be so kind to refer to the original author

Comment: @zerkms I marked the question as duplicate and added a reference

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are mixing the concept of the index of an array with the actual element of that array.

In short, arrayName[2].length returns the length of the second element.
The second element in this case is 2, its length being undefined.

While a good approach for achieving your goal is to use the library [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
arr = [1,2,2,2,3];

function countDuplicate(arr, dup) {
  return (_.filter(arr, function(num){ 
    return num == dup; 
  })).length;
}

console.log(countDuplicate(arr, 2));
```

The fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hn5tR/).